# Plotting ideas for large number of unique catagories

Tags: python, data-visualization, many-categories

I have 209 unique categories within a column, is there a nice way to plot it ?

- I am grouping the 209 unique categories with their respective cost column. How should I represent it visually ?

Below is a small example of the output for the average of the cost grouped by the category(I am only showing one, there are 209 such rows):

1000-1299 lbs Wheel Skid Steer Loader,4747.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it well, your data is low dimensional, only one column of categories and another column of prices

I would order the categories for cost in the abscissa axis and its cost on the ordinate axis..